# How to load interstitial ads admob on adview?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, adview

This is the code for when I use native express ads (working)

```
RelativeLayout mAdView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView);
NativeExpressAdView adObj = new NativeExpressAdView(this);
adObj.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.native_ad_unit_id));
adObj.setAdSize(new AdSize(800,800));
mAdView.addView(adObj);

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adObj.loadAd(request);
```

And this code is for when I use interstitial ads (working)

```
InterstitialAd adObj = new InterstitialAd(this);
adObj.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_id));

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adObj.loadAd(request);
adObj.show();
```

Can I use Interstitial ads like native express, not pop up just on layout?

Comment: Did you publish your app before? Because it may not work if you haven't published it before. You can test the interstitial ads though by adding your test device ID.

Comment: thanks for your commend,

yes, my app is published and my code is work, but, can i use Interstitial ads like native express not pop up just on layout?

Answer (score 0):

**Interstitial's main feature is that to show ads on Layout, but If you want to popup your ad then use another**

Answer (score 0):

```
InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
public void show(Context context) {

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);

    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(context.getResources().getString(R.string.id_ad_interstitial));

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
}

public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        interstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```